# How to get G (generator) point from bouncycastle ECCurve in Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Hi i have this curve from bouncycastle:

```
    BigInteger prime = new BigInteger("57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564821041");
    BigInteger A = new BigInteger("7");
    BigInteger B = new BigInteger("43308876546767276905765904595650931995942111794451039583252968842033849580414");

    ECCurve curve = new ECCurve.Fp(prime, A, B);
```

I'm looking for the G point to generate other points from the curve but I can't find a way to get it

Comment: Where did you get the curve parameters from? If this is well-known curve in some standard then that standard will also specify the base point G. Otherwise, just pick your own point G of maximal order. You need to know the order of the curve, or you can compute the order using something like Sage or Pari.

Answer (score 0):

These curve parameters are taken from an early draft of RFC 4357 ([draft-popov-cryptopro-cpalgs-01](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-popov-cryptopro-cpalgs-01#page-46)). In that draft you can see they give a base point:

x 2,
y 401897405659037503335449422937059775635739389905545080690979365213431566280

However this is only test data and it is only used in the BC tests for historical reasons. You would be better off with actual standardized curves. If they specifically have to be from the GOST standards, you could check those provided by the `org.bouncycastle.asn1.cryptopro.ECGOST3410NamedCurves` class.